# Ext4 switching to read only mode

Tags: 13.10, ext4, read-only

I have very frustrating problem. My server randomly switches / mount to read only without any pattern.

Only message that I've found in logs is:

```
htree_dirblock_to_tree:920: inode #14286877: block 57155636: comm rsync: bad entry in directory: rec_len % 4 != 0
```

I've changed new hard disk, new controller, done memtest. Last thing that is left to replace is motherboard, but this doesn't make any sense.

Any advice?